# Update query in for loop

Tags: php, mysql, sql

why it's not working..

i want to update my table in database this is my code.

```
for ($i=0; $i <83 ; $i++) { 

    $link="this is test".$i;
    $sql = "UPDATE tbl_gallery_images SET   thumbnail_url='$link' WHERE gallery_id=1";

    // Prepare statement
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    // execute the query
    $stmt->execute();

    echo $link."<br>";
}
```

when i echo that link it's show 100% right but  in db just update 82 number in all rows even it is in loop. 
thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you mean to have the same gallery updated - `WHERE gallery_id=1`?

Comment: remove `"this is test"` from your saving string `$link`

Comment: It updates to 0 and then 1 and then 2 and then... up to 82 is the last one.  What do you expect?

Comment: @NigelRen yes the attribute of db have value **this is test 82** is all rows..

Comment: @dean i can't update string??

Comment: @AbraCadaver yes i want that it save 1,2,3,4,5...82 in db but it not..

Comment: Your table tbl_gallery_images must be having only one row with gallery_id  = 1

Comment: @RohitShetty not at all. it have 83 rows.

Comment: `WHERE gallery_id=1` change to `WHERE gallery_id=$i`

Comment: So its correct. Your query runs in a loop so all rows with gallery_id = 1  will be updated each time. Finally when the loop executes for last time it updates every row with 'this is test 82'

Comment: @RohitShetty but it is in loop.. loop start update one row again loop start and update another row and so on.. this is what i want to do.. how can i do that?

Comment: So if your gallery_id value is different for each row, your query is wrong. Like @Alex mentioned, you have to change to WHERE gallery_id=$i

Comment: @Alex when i do this it just update 82 in all rows of db..

Comment: can you share your table structure?

Comment: @RohitShetty no no my gallery_id is same for whole loop. means i want to update all 83 rows which have gallery_id=1

Comment: In that case, you cannot use gallery_id in where condition. You need to use some other column which uniquely identifies each row.

Comment: @RohitShetty when i use other column its working but i want to update according to gallery_id..

Comment: But tell me,what is the purpose of gallery_id if it is not uniqe?

Comment: then use 'and' in your where clause. So your query will be  UPDATE tbl_gallery_images SET   thumbnail_url='$link' WHERE gallery_id=1 AND other_column=value

Comment: @Alex it is foreign key of tbl_gallery

Comment: And what is your primary key of tbl_gallery?

Comment: @Alex i guess he meant gallery_id is primary key of tbl_gallery

Comment: yes @Alex he is right

Answer (score 0):

> `UPDATE tbl_gallery_images SET thumbnail_url = '$link' WHERE gallery_id = 1`

As it is, this query updates column `thumbnail_url` in *all records* that have `gallery_id = 1`. Running the same query 84 times in a loop results in the same set of records being updated again and again in each iteration, with an increasing `thumbnail_url`. After the last iteration, all records where `gallery_id = 1` end up with `thumbnail_url = 'this is test83`.

A sensible solution would be to add another criteria in the `WHERE` clause, in order to update just one record *per iteration*. Assuming that you have some integer column called `id` to disambiguate the records where `gallery_id = 1`, you would typically go:

```
`UPDATE tbl_gallery_images SET thumbnail_url = '$link' WHERE gallery_id = 1 AND id = $i`
```